# PHPExcel - Export Missing Row

Tags: phpexcel

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code as it exports the headers ok but i am missing 1 record from the export. Many Thanks

```
$rowNumber = 1; //start in cell 1   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $col = 'A'; // start at column A    

  // returns title row
       if ( $rowNumber == 1 ){
        $headers = array_keys($row);
            foreach($headers as $header) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$header);
            $col++;
            }
        $rowNumber++;
      }else{ //returns content rows
       $col = 'A';
       $rowNumber
        foreach($row as $cell) {          
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);          
        $col++;       
        } 
      $rowNumber++;       
      }  
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('A',3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only displaying the headers for the first row retrieved from your database, not the data from that row....

```
$rowNumber = 1; //start in cell 1   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $col = 'A'; // start at column A    

    // returns title row
    if ( $rowNumber == 1 ){
        $headers = array_keys($row);
        foreach($headers as $header) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$header);
            $col++;
        }
        $rowNumber++;
    }
    $col = 'A';
    foreach($row as $cell) {          
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);          
        $col++;       
    }  
    $rowNumber++;
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('A',3);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you help me fix it? need it to return the header and all data in the table. $result is my sql query.

Comment: The code I've quoted in my answer ___will___ fix it